# ScenicView 8.7.0 does not load the opened JAVA FX application in it to inspect the elements

Tags: javafx, netbeans, scenebuilder, testfx

I have ScenicView 8.7.0 installed with JDK 8. I need to inspect the JAVA FX application which is running on Ubuntu 16.04(Hope Linux version is not the concern).

ScenicView does find the opened JAVA FX application as per the following logs, but in UI of ScenicView, no application is getting displayed. ["Scanning for JavaFX applications" message displayed in ScenicView with endless spinner]. Any help appreciated.

At ScenicView terminal logs I am getting following lines

```
Platform running
Launching ScenicView v8.7.0
Startup done
Creating server
Server done
Number of running Java applications found: 1
Obtaining properties for Java application with PID:2731
1 JavaFX applications found
Loading agent from: /home/pravin.ware/RF/scenicView.jar
Loading agent for:sun.tools.attach.LinuxAttachProvider@5dec8822: 2731 ID:2731 on port:7559 took:0ms using agent defined in /home/pravin.ware/RF/scenicView.jar
Launching agent server on:7559:7558:2731:true
Finding RemoteConnector connection for agent...
2018-09-17T10:49:35.388Z [ INFO] CSS Monitoring is about to start
2018-09-17T10:49:35.493Z [ INFO] CSS Monitoring started
2018-09-17T10:49:35.493Z [ INFO] starting to monitor physical files
RemoteConnector found:Proxy[RemoteConnector,RemoteObjectInvocationHandler[UnicastRef [liveRef: [endpoint:[127.0.1.1:46501](remote),objID:[5a63221f:165e72659de:-7fff, 7020829788853889890]]]]]
Remote agent started on port:7559
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem finally. It had nothing to do with Scenicview.jar. All went wrong was the Application I was testing. The application was the hybrid app (Swing+ JavaFX). Hence, ScenicView was failing to locate the elements.