# ScenicView does not show application

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to use ScenicView 11 but it doesn't show the application. When running I get

```
Platform running
Launching ScenicView v11.0.2
Startup done
Creating server
Server done
Number of running Java applications found: 4
Obtaining properties for Java application with PID:13060
Obtaining properties for Java application with PID:14856
Obtaining properties for Java application with PID:6140
1 JavaFX applications found
Loading agent from: C:\ScenicView\scenicview\lib\scenicview.jar
Loading agent for:sun.tools.attach.AttachProviderImpl@40ffae21: 13060 ID:13060 on port:7559 took:101ms using agent defined in C:\ScenicView\scenicview\lib\scenicview.jar
Remote agent started on port:7559
RemoteApp connected on:7558 stageID:StageID [appID=13060, stageID=984143142, name=null]
```

And the Scanning for JavaFX applications rotating progress bar stays there forever. I found [ScenicView 8.7.0 does not load the opened JAVA FX application in it to inspect the elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52366451/scenicview-8-7-0-does-not-load-the-opened-java-fx-application-in-it-to-inspect-t) but my application doesn't use Swing. Yet when ScenicView is running and I start my app I get

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/embed/swing/SwingFXUtils
    at org.fxconnector.node.SVDummyNode.convertToAwtImage(SVDummyNode.java:154)
    at org.fxconnector.node.SVDummyNode.setRemote(SVDummyNode.java:139)
    at org.fxconnector.StageControllerImpl.update(StageControllerImpl.java:355)
    at org.fxconnector.StageControllerImpl.setEventDispatcher(StageControllerImpl.java:309)
    at org.fxconnector.remote.RuntimeAttach$1.lambda$setEventDispatcher$4(RuntimeAttach.java:113)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:606)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 12 more
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/embed/swing/SwingFXUtils
    at org.fxconnector.node.SVDummyNode.convertToAwtImage(SVDummyNode.java:154)
    at org.fxconnector.node.SVDummyNode.setRemote(SVDummyNode.java:139)
    at org.fxconnector.StageControllerImpl.update(StageControllerImpl.java:355)
    at org.fxconnector.StageControllerImpl.configurationUpdated(StageControllerImpl.java:592)
    at org.fxconnector.remote.RuntimeAttach$1.lambda$configurationUpdated$1(RuntimeAttach.java:99)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

But these are not coming from my app. I tried both from Eclipse and launching as a jar and neither work. Using JavaFX 14/15 and JDK 15. Any ideas?

Comment: Try adding `javafx.swing` to your project?

Comment: @JoséPereda I added ` --add-modules=javafx.swing` and it works, but why do i need it if my project doesn't use it?

Comment: If you load it as java agent it probably doesn't bring its dependencies with it, so these have to be included in the project.

Comment: @JoséPereda huh ok. thanks for the help